# I can't figure it out why this simple videoView demo doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I'm learning how `videoView` works. I followed a tutorial; this is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.simoc.videoviewdemo.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my mainActivity.java:

```
<package com.simoc.videoviewdemo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    myVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.myvideo.3gp);

//myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4"));
            //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myvideo.3gp";
            //myVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            //Log.i("MY_PATH: ", path);
            myVideoView.start();
        }
        }
```

Ok. First I create a "raw" folder unde "res" and put my video in it. I've set the videoPath and all works fine.
So I decided to try to stream a video. It works the link in the code but it doesn't work a random YouTube link (and I don't understand why).
But the real question is: why this 2 lines:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myvideo.3gp";
        myVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
```

are wrong? I put the video in the `/storage/emulated/0/myvideo` but I always get the error `can't play the video`. I didn't find a different way to use `videoView` and so I really don't know where is my fault.
Oh, in the manifest I added the permissons:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this don't add extension name

```
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo;
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
myVideoView.start();
```

Comment: No that line is correct and it works fine. The line that doesn't work are the 2 I have underlined in the end, when I try to access to a folder in the internal storage of my phone. And there I've tried to delete the extension but it doesn't work